# Conditional comparison of information from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to retrieve the name of the moviestars who starred in `Star Wars` and who are males (`M`).

```
StarsIn(movieTitle, movieYear, starName)
MovieStar(name, address, gender, birthdate)
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT moviestar.name 
FROM StarsIn, moviestar 
WHERE movietitle='Star Wars' AND moviestar.gender = 'M'
```

However, I retrieve all the names from `moviestar.name` who are males. It should only be limited to `Mark Hamill` and `Harrison Ford`. I also get duplicates. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not joined the two database tables.

```sql
select s.starName
  from StarsIn s
  join MovieStar m
    on s.starName = m.name
 where s.movieTitle = 'Star Wars'
   and m.gender = 'M'
```

Refer to any SQL tutorial, for example [SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you have to join the 2 tables to get the data, your join is missing. Try the following -

```
SELECT ms.name 
FROM StarsIn si, moviestar ms
WHERE 
si.starName = ms.name
AND si.movietitle='Star Wars' 
AND moviestar.gender = 'M'
```

Comment: Ahh! I didn't know I needed the join there. Thank you it made sense.

Comment: @jubibanna the SQL in this answer does not use [ANSI join syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) which is recommended.

Comment: Thank you, @pinakeep. Your answer made more sense in regard to the book I'm reading (Database Systems: The Complete Book"  from 2014)